# Android: After loading, the image hide others

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this issue: I've created a FrameLayout with two transparent button on the edges (left and right)

```
     <FrameLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        >

    <ImageButton
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_previous_item"
            android:id="@+id/btn_item_prev"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            />

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:id="@+id/myimage"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            />

    <ImageButton
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next_item"
            android:id="@+id/btn_item_next"
            android:layout_gravity="right"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

On studio this is the result:
[image]

And for me is OK. It's what I want. But when I run the app, this is the results:

[image]

The behaviour is this: When start I see the two ImageButtons, but when Picasso finish to load the image, the first button (on the left) is hidden by the image at center.

I don't understand why... I try to use a Relative Layout before, but with same results...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in framelayout the z-index is define by the order views are added, change the order of your views, add the imageview first and then your navigation buttons

Answer (score 1):

Try to Use Like This:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        >

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:id="@+id/myimage"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            />
     <ImageButton
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_previous_item"
            android:id="@+id/btn_item_prev"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            />
    <ImageButton
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next_item"
            android:id="@+id/btn_item_next"
            android:layout_gravity="right"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a RelativeLayout, please notice the order of the elements.

ImageView should be the first element inside the RelativeLayout so it won't block the ImageButton.

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:id="@+id/myimage"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        />

<ImageButton
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next_item"
        android:id="@+id/btn_item_next"
        android:layout_gravity="right"/>

<ImageButton
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_previous_item"
        android:id="@+id/btn_item_prev"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   <FrameLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        >


    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:id="@+id/myimage"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            />
  <ImageButton
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_previous_item"
            android:id="@+id/btn_item_prev"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            />

    <ImageButton
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next_item"
            android:id="@+id/btn_item_next"
            android:layout_gravity="right"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

FramLayout place controll on by other. so, in your design , first image button then imageview. so, image button are hidden by imageview.

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        >
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:id="@+id/myimage"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            />
 <ImageButton
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_previous_item"
            android:id="@+id/btn_item_prev"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            />
 <ImageButton
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next_item"
            android:id="@+id/btn_item_next"
            android:layout_gravity="right"/>
 </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your two buttons above the **imageview** then buttons will not be hidden. Code will be

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        >



    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:id="@+id/myimage"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            />

    <ImageButton
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_previous_item"
            android:id="@+id/btn_item_prev"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            />

    <ImageButton
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next_item"
            android:id="@+id/btn_item_next"
            android:layout_gravity="right"/>

</FrameLayout>
```